# How can I prevent getting an AttributeError after reloading a cog?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, attributeerror

I am working on a Discord bot which handles music requests among other things. Whenever I change stuff in a cog and then reload it, I get an error message like `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'XXXX'` error for the particular command.

For example, starting with this code for the cog:

```py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.guild_only()
    @commands.check(audio_playing)
    @commands.check(in_voice_channel)
    @commands.check(is_audio_requester)
    async def loop(self, ctx):
        """Activates/Deactivates the loop for a song."""
        state = self.get_state(ctx.guild)
        status = state.now_playing.toggle_loop()
        if status is None:
            return await ctx.send(
                embed=discord.Embed(title=":no_entry:  Unable to toggle loop.", color=discord.Color.red()))
        else:
            return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
                title=f":repeat:  Loop: {'**Enabled**' if state.now_playing.loop else '**Disabled**'}.",
                color=self.bot.get_embed_color(ctx.guild)))
```

which calls a helper method `get_state`:

```py
    def get_state(self, guild):
        """Gets the state for `guild`, creating it if it does not exist."""
        if guild.id in self.states:
            return self.states[guild.id]
        else:
            self.states[guild.id] = GuildState()
            return self.states[guild.id]
```

which creates an instance of this `GuildState` class:

```py
class GuildState:
    """Helper class managing per-guild state."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.volume = 1.0
        self.playlist = []
        self.message_queue = []
        self.skip_votes = set()
        self.now_playing = None
        self.control_message = None
        self.loop = False
        self.skipped = False

    def is_requester(self, user):
        return self.now_playing.requested_by == user
```

Then I use code like this to make the bot respond to the command `play URL` by joining a voice channel:

```py
if not state.now_playing:
    self._play_song(client, state, video)
```

where `_play_song` does:

```py
    def _play_song(self, client, state, song):
        state.now_playing = song
    # Other things are not relevant
```

Now if I try to reload the cog, the next time `loop` is called I get an error like:

```py
In loop:
  File "C:\Users\Dominik\PycharmProjects\AlchiReWrite\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dominik\PycharmProjects\AlchiReWrite\cogs\music.py", line 220, in loop
    status = state.now_playing.toggle_loop()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toggle_loop'
```

I tried using exception handling with `try/except AttributeError` to ignore the error, but it didn't resolve the problem.

Why does this occur, and how can I fix or prevent the problem? I query `state` for every command which has to do with music, is it maybe related to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reload the cog, the `states` dictionary in your cog will be empty. With `state = self.get_state(ctx.guild)`, a new `GuildState` object is created. From the `__init__` function of the `GuildState` class, `self.now_playing` is set to `None`.

Because of this, `status = state.now_playing.toggle_loop()` will throw an `AttributeError` as `None` has no attributes (in this case, no `toggle_loop` attribute).

If you want to get rid of these errors, you will need to set `self.now_playing` correctly to something that does have the needed attributes.

If you want to keep the `states` dictionary as is, you can save it before reloading your cog and restore it. The below example assumes that the cog class is named `TestCog`.

```py
@client.command()
async def reload(ctx):
    temp = client.get_cog('TestCog').states
    client.reload_extension('cog')
    client.get_cog('TestCog').states = temp
```

Note that this may break your cog if you change how `GuildState` is created, as you are restoring the previous version of `states`.

Comment: Would you be able just from your knowledge/the code snippet to tell me what I could do about the error.? I see that `self.now_playing` is set to None but changing that would "skip" the AttributeError if I set it to something else?

Comment: @Dominik I assume your code changes `state.now_playing` from `None` that it gets the `toggle_next` attribute somewhere, maybe when the bot initially connects to a voice channel? You need to do that again. If you add it to your question I may be able to help.

Comment: I will add something to the question.